# Elastic python to extract last 1hr tracing

Tags: python, elasticsearch, search, kibana

My application is java and onboared to elastic. I can write python script with app ame, after testing connection to elastic server. I am in need to get last 1hr tracing details through devtool/API/python.

```
es.Elastcsearch("https://localhost:9200")
```

And then query: `{ "match": { "name": "1NN_java"}}`

If I want to get list of transaction, how can we get with API ? How to get Last 1hr tracing through python ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In elastic to see last one hour tracing, we can go to service -- change time frame to 1hr. When we want to see same from python code..how can we do it ?